# Is there anyway to find library path dynamically in CMake?

Tags: cmake, linker, shared-libraries

I have `libcurl.so` in three different paths. lets say `/usr/lib` , `/opt/a/.../lib/`, `/opt/b/.../lib/`

I want to link proper library while building. How to write CMakeLists.txt to do that?

As of now I have hard coded to find it in `/usr/lib/`

```
project (mylib)

find_library(LIB_CURL_LIBRARY NAMES curl HINTS "/usr/lib/")

target_link_libraries (mylib curl)
```

Answer (score 1):

Command `find_library` actually searches many places, which can also be adjusted by a user (the person, who uses the CMake project with `find_library` call, but do not modifies `CMakeLists.txt`).

Also, via `HINTS` and `PATHS` you (as the project's developer) may add more hints to search, and these hints could also be made modifiable by a user.

You may find complete description about search paths in [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/command/find_library.html).

When decide how to make `find_library` to search in the specific path, you need to "classify" origin that path. Some common cases:

1. Is the path a **standard** one for specific OS or distro? If so, CMake usually searches this path by default.
2. Does the path come from the **custom installation** of the package? If so, the user could assign **installation prefix** to some variable (e.g. `XXX_ROOT`, where XXX is a package name or abbreviation), which is used as `PATHS` or `HINTS` in your `find_library` call.
3. Does the path come from the **custom installation** prefix, common for **many packages**? If so, the user could assign that common prefix to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable, and `find_library` automatically will take this prefix into account.

Note, that `find_library` is usually used in a `FindXXX.cmake` module (which is activated via `find_package(XXX)`). Such module could include additional logic for find additional possible library locations according to the system introspection.